# How does the matching JS code using indexOf work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I've managed to copy some JS over into my doc, and I've got it working. But I don't entirely understand how its doing it.

It's a search function to match with data in a table and hide any rows that don't match.

But I don't understand the active line of code that actually searches and matches. Would someone explain it?

```js
$('#searchBar').keyup(function() {
  searchFunction($(this).val());
});

function searchFunction(value) {
  $('#results tr').each(function() {
    var found = 'false';

    $(this).each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        found = 'true';
      }
    });

    if (found === 'true') {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

  })
};
```

It's this line I can't get my head around:

```js
if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
  found = 'true';
}
```

I understand how it changes the variable to true, but I don't understand how it matches the data in the Table row with the Value fed in.

Comment: `this` refers to the `<tr>`. The code gets all text inside the row as one long string, turns it lower case, then calls `indexOf()` on it, passing the value. This returns the position of the value inside the string, or `-1` if not found.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Please rename your title that relates to the problem at hand - at the moment it is not very useful to readers who want to know if it is something they can help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converts the value you sent to the function to lowercase, and then looks at the data in the row. It converts that to lowercase too, and sees if there is a match using indexof, which is covered here: [How to use IndexOf in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776280/how-to-use-indexof-in-jquery)

Basically, the indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. It returns -1 if the value to search does not occur.

Consider searching for "test"

```
var str = "Hello this is a test";
var n = str.indexOf("test");
```

The result of n will be: 16, ergo, as in your script, larger than 0... and "found"

Answer (score 0):

What it does is

For each rows in my table "result"
  If one of all these values, that I look in lowercase, is equal to what I typed in the "searchBar" in lower case, more than one time, then I found it, and so found = "true"

Comment: Your answer is confusing especially the part about `more than one time`.

Answer (score 0):

From search bar key press event will be triggered and value of search bar will passed to search function

```
$("#searchBar").keyup(function() {
  searchFunction($(this).val());
});

function searchFunction(value) {
  //value will contain the value of search bar
  $("#results tr").each(function() {
    //assuming value is not there in tr
    var found = "false";
    //now searching for each tr for value
    $(this).each(function() {
      //converting to lower case and comparing each value with searchbar value
      if (
        $(this)
          .text()
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0
      ) {
        found = "true";
      }
    });
    //actual showing/hiding row
    if (found === "true") {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

if need more info about index of
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp
@MattCouthon let me know if you need anything else